# Remove text that doesn't have its own element

Tags: jquery, html, text

I have some HTML that looks like this:

```
<div class="field">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="sourcedidSource" value="SYSTEM">SYSTEM
    <span class="someClass"></span>
</div>
```

I need to remove the `SYSTEM` text after `sourcedidSource` while keeping everything else intact. I tried `$('.field').text().remove();`, but that removes the `input` and `span` elements as well. What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually a lot easier to work with textnodes without jQuery

```
var node = document.getElementById('sourcedidSource').nextSibling;
node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
```

Or the funky jQuery version

```
$($('#sourcedidSource').get(0).nextSibling).remove();
```

Comment: Ah, the simplicity of raw javascript coming in handy. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `contents()` and `filter()` to get the `textNode` within the `.field` and `remove()` them. Try this:

```
$('.field').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
}).remove();
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/kx1wsq4h/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$('.field').text().remove();`

Do `$('#sourcedidSource').text('')` OR `$('#sourcedidSource').text().remove()`

This will target the specific input field you have and set the text content to an empty string, `''`.

Comment: Note that this will completely overwrite all the HTML in the element. Also `$('#sourcedidSource').text().remove()` will give you a syntax error, as `text()` returns a string which has no `remove()` method.

Comment: Yep, you are right sir! But I thought the only contents of the HTML element in question `input` is the text that the OP wanted to remove. Your answer is def better though ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There is your solution : https://jsfiddle.net/yuswddpg/

```
$(".field").contents().filter(function(){
   return (this.nodeType == 3);
}).remove();
```